How to plot potential function with Heaviside step function
How to plot $\frac{V(\varphi)}{V_{0}}$ with respect to $\frac{\varphi}{\varphi_{0}}$ for the following $V(\phi)$, where $\lambda_{0}=-1.0\times10^{-14},e=2.718,N_{UV}=15,g_{0}=0.0217,k=(16\pi^{2})^{-1}$ and $V_{0}$ is such that $V(\varphi_{min})=0$, also $\Theta(\varphi-e\varphi_{0})$ is a heaviside step function.
$V(\phi)=\frac{\lambda_{0}}{4}\varphi^{4}[1-\frac{441}{32}\frac{k^{2}g_{0}^{6}}{\lambda_{0}}\ln^{2}(\frac{\varphi}{\varphi_{0}})+\frac{3k^{2}g_{0}^{6}}{2\lambda_{0}}(N_{UV}-1)\ln^{2}(\frac{\varphi}{e\varphi_{0}})\Theta(\varphi-e\varphi_{0})]+V_{0}$

Please provide Mathematica code,your  chance to get helpful answers will increase significantly
